# Tilt Shaped Bordered Div in css3

Tags: html, css, border, transform

i am trying to design a **bordered shape div** with css3 like a bordered square but tilted from the right hand side to some extend...

Here's what i am trying to design:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wcxi.png

I tried to skew the div by **css3 transformation** but it also skews the map also and content inside the div and skews both side of the div

**My demo:-** http://jsfiddle.net/znsmG/

HTML Code:-

```
<div class="map_canvas">
    <div class="map_area" data-showcontrols="true" data-lat="-34.397" data-lng="150.644" data-zoom="7"></div>           
</div>
```

Css:-

```
.map_canvas { border: 10px solid #d2d828; position:relative; }
.map_area { height: 400px; width:100%; }
```

Any method or something to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just created this beauty from **css3 transformation**...

The trick, i implemented is skew the root container to `10deg` and parent container to `-10deg`, and overflow hidden to the outer container and vice versa...

**Working Demo :-** http://jsfiddle.net/znsmG/3/

**Css:-**

```
.map_contain {
    border-left: 10px solid #D2D828;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.map_canvas {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #D2D828;
    border-right: 10px solid #D2D828;
    border-top: 10px solid #D2D828;
    margin: 0 40px 0 -40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transform: skewX(10deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(10deg);
}
.map_area {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 -35px 0 40px;
    transform: skewX(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg);
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: works really well, but it also tilts text!! any idea how to prevent that?